# SELECT all matching two fields and grouping by those two fields with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, grouping

I have a messages system which doubles out as a message system and chat system, these are differentiated by a field called source.

I have the messages sections sorting and grouping properly however in the chat section it's not grouping these accordingly, please see my SQL below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages
WHERE ( senderID = "1" OR receiverID = "1" ) 
AND source = "1" 
GROUP BY receiverID, senderID 
ORDER BY addedDate DESC LIMIT 10
```

So the result i am expecting is just one per match, i.e. one per conversation

however am getting two for some reason.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: can you provide with table data

Comment: When grouping rows, you have to specify the columns in your SELECT statement.

Comment: @JeroenBolle i have stated the fields it's still not grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably getting two answers per chat because you would have each person in both positions

```
ChatID  Sender Receiver
1       1      2
2       2      1
3       1      2
4       2      1

So, you'll have a record grouped by 
Sender / Receiver
1        2         and
2        1
```

I think what you are looking for is distinct people in the conversation where the above should be considered "ONE CHAT" regardless of the position they are in.  To correct this, I would do something like...

```
select 
      PreQuery.*,
      m2.Message,
      m2.SenderID,
      m2.ReceiverID
   from
      ( SELECT 
              if( m.senderID < m.receiverID, m.senderID, m.receiverID ) as Person1,
              if( m.senderID < m.receiverID, m.receiverID, m.senderID ) as Person2,
              max( m.ID ) as LastMessageIDPerChat,
              max( m.AddedDate ) as LastMessageDate
           FROM 
              messages m
           WHERE 
                  m.Source = "1"
              AND "1" IN ( SenderID, ReceiverID )
           GROUP BY
              Person1, 
              Person2
           ORDER BY 
              m.AddedDate DESC 
           LIMIT 10 ) PreQuery

         JOIN Messages m2
            on PreQuery.LastMessageIDPerChat = m2.ID
```

This will ensure that whichever ID is lower will always be in the first position, and whichever person's ID is higher is always in second position to prevent false duplicates as described above.

Also note... GROUP BY is typically expecting all non-group by fields to be associated with some aggregation, otherwise, it will just grab the first instance of a record found with a qualifying condition.  So, if you want to include same people in conversations on different days, you'll want to add "AddedDate" to the group by so it could have...

```
Person1   Person2  on 4/20
Person1   Person3  on 4/20
Person3   Person4  on 4/20
Person1   Person2  on 4/18
Person1   Person5  on 4/17
Person3   Person4  on 4/15
```

To get the status of who sent last, I had to wrap the query of paired people per conversation and get the last ID of that conversation.  THEN, take that and re-join back to messages on that ID (if ID is actually the primary key ID of the messages table, adjust as needed).   From the join, I can get the last message for the conversation AND who the sender ID and Receiver ID were for that transaction (and any other data you want from the now alias "m2" reference).

Comment: that's exactly what i want to do, however looking at the senderID, what is the sender id is bigger than the receiver id?

Comment: @AndréFigueira, thats why both IF() check the sender compared to receiver.  If sender is greater, then receiver becomes first person position and sender becomes second person position.

Comment: I see ok, but then that means that the lower id will always be the receiver right?

Comment: @AndréFigueira, no, either person could be in position 1.  This is just returning WHO ARE THE PEOPLE in the chat session, not who's in what position.  As noted, they will EACH be a sender at one time or another.  This is just to prevent the return values of a/b or b/a of the same conversation.  Do you want to know who sent the last action?

Comment: ok i see, yes i need to know what the content of the last action is, we can a content field, and we need to display the most recent message on the inbox. and at the moment we have been using the id to make another call to get it as with this method it was blank on some and on others it would show the first message ever sent

Comment: @AndréFigueira, see revised answer

Comment: @DRapp hey i have tried to use your code but it does not order from the messages. it works well by bringing the recent message on top but does not order the message list from most recent

Comment: @krushiovida, the INNER query ordered by the date to get the most recent 10 messages.  If you need the OUTER results to ALSO be in date order, add an ORDER BY clause after the join/on clause.

Comment: @DRapp can you work this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38032658/mysql-query-group-by-and-then-order-by-most-recent-grouped-with-condition

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your IDs aren't integers?

```
SELECT
    receiverID,
    senderID,
    MAX(addedDate) as maxAddedDate
FROM 
    messages 
WHERE 
    ( 
        senderID = 1
        OR receiverID = 1 
    )  
    AND source = 1
GROUP BY
    receiverID, 
    senderID  
ORDER BY 
    addedDate DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: It's exactly the same, they are both ints.

Comment: essentially what i am trying to do is match a conversation, a conversation can be from or too us hence the receiver and sender id being or

Comment: Then you shouldn't use quotes. I updated. This query will give each unique combination of senderID and receiverID where either receiverID or senderID is 1.

Comment: even without wuotes gives the same result

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
SELECT
    receiverID,
    senderID,
    MAX(addedDate) as maxAddedDate
FROM messages 
WHERE ( senderID = 1 OR receiverID = 1) AND source = 1
GROUP BY receiverID, senderID  
ORDER BY addedDate DESC
```

You have not mentioned any aggregation for group by fields.

If your having multiple records according to any group by fields then what should happen?

you should have sum, count,...

Comment: well if it matches a conversation e.g. where the user id can be receiver or sender and the interacter id can be sender or receiver