# MySQL Query, group by and then order by most recent grouped with condition

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this code that groups message according to ID of a logged in user, The code works great as it is. But now i wish to make some modification which i don't know to implement

**my query code**

```
 $query_messages = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT 
      PreQuery.*,
      m2.message,
      m2.senderID,
      m2.receiverID
   from
      ( SELECT 
              if( m.senderID < m.receiverID, m.senderID, m.receiverID ) as Person1,
              if( m.senderID < m.receiverID, m.receiverID, m.senderID ) as Person2,
              max( m.messageID ) as LastMessageIDPerChat,
              max( m.date ) as LastMessageDate
           FROM 
              messages m
           WHERE 
                   '$user' IN ( senderID, receiverID ) 
           GROUP BY
              Person1, 
              Person2
           ORDER BY 
              m.date ASC
           LIMIT 10 ) PreQuery

         JOIN messages m2
            on PreQuery.LastMessageIDPerChat = m2.messageID    ORDER BY 
              date DESC");
$row_messages = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_messages);
$totalRows_messages = mysqli_num_rows($query_messages);
```

**DB structure**

[image]

**Brief explanation**

**Lets say** 
*the variable of a logged in user is **$user**

In the database the user can either be **senderID** or **receiverID**

When the **$user** deletes his conversation, his messages are updated from **0** to **1** in senderdelete column or receiverdelete column*

**Were the problem is:-**

I would wish to modify the MySQLI query code and add this to the query

```
if $user is the sender then senderdelete should be value 0
```

AND

```
if $user is the receiver then receiverdelete should be value 0
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added this in the where clause and it seems to be working

```
WHERE 
'$myid' IN ( senderID ) AND senderdelete = 0 
OR
'$myid' IN ( receiverID ) AND receiverdelete = 0
```

Full updated code

```
 $query_messages = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT 
      PreQuery.*,
      m2.message,
      m2.senderID,
      m2.receiverID,
      m2.senderdelete,
      m2.receiverdelete
   from
      ( SELECT 
              if( m.senderID < m.receiverID, m.senderID, m.receiverID ) as Person1,
              if( m.senderID < m.receiverID, m.receiverID, m.senderID ) as Person2,
              max( m.messageID ) as LastMessageIDPerChat,
              max( m.date ) as LastMessageDate
           FROM 
              messages m
           WHERE 
                   '$myid' IN ( senderID) AND senderdelete = 0 OR '$myid' IN ( receiverID) AND receiverdelete = 0 

           GROUP BY
              Person1, 
              Person2
           ORDER BY 
              m.date ASC
           LIMIT 10 ) PreQuery

         JOIN messages m2
            on PreQuery.LastMessageIDPerChat = m2.messageID    ORDER BY 
              date DESC");
$row_messages = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_messages);
$totalRows_messages = mysqli_num_rows($query_messages);
```

Comment: To avoid future ambiguities, especially on expanded complex conditions, try wrapping such as  WHERE ( '$user' = senderID and senderdelete = 0 ) OR ( '$user' = receiverID and receiverdelete = 0 )

Comment: I will employ the changes in my programmings @DRapp .i'm great-full for the support